# Is there a standard spatial reference to indicate that a raster is aspatial?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I have an aspatial raster file representing a decay kernel centered around the center pixel in the raster.  This file sometimes gets to be large, so it has been very convenient to store this kernel as a tiled GDAL raster so that I can more efficiently and easily access tiles of the underlying array without needing to address the whole array.  This raster currently has a spatial reference, but since it doesn't actually represent anything spatially, a spatial reference doesn't really make sense.

Some folks on my team find the fact that there's a spatial reference to be confusing, but if I don't define a spatial reference, QGIS will prompt me for the spatial reference each time I open up the raster.

So, is there a standard way to indicate that this raster does not actually represent any real-world quantity nor a place on earth?  I'm hoping for an EPSG code or something like that, but I haven't found anything related.

I also realize that I could just *not* define the spatial reference when creating the raster, but I'd prefer to avoid the complaints of spatial software packages as mentioned.

Comment: Either a TIFF is a picture (has no spatial reference) or it has a spatial basis (and therefore should be a GeoTIFF). A model that represents decay from a place doesn't sound particularly aspatial to me, especially if the location is based on a raster which does have a spatial reference. In general, the way to show a GeoTIFF is aspatial is to make it a TIFF instead.

Comment: GeoPackage standard defines two undefined CRS `The record with an srs_id of -1 SHALL be used for undefined Cartesian coordinate reference systems. The record with an srs_id of 0 SHALL be used for undefined geographic coordinate reference systems.` Maybe if you save your rasted as GeoPackage raster with srs_id=-1 it would be interpreted automatically right. The draft for JSON-FG also defines this https://docs.ogc.org/DRAFTS/21-045.html#crs-engineering-2d, maybe that could become a generic standard.

Comment: In my case, the solution was to just not define the spatial reference in the geotiff, which, much to my surprise, GDAL had no complaint about.  This must have been a change to GDAL in the past few years.  So @Vince, if you would like to make your comment an answer, I'll be happy to select it.

Comment: @user30184, that's a great idea for the geopackage format, specifically!  In my case, using the features of GDAL's GeoTiff driver seem more attractive, so I went with that instead.